# Setting one data attribute clears other as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm have a function that sets removes all values from a data-attribute, selected-ids. Whenever that I set selected-ids length to zero the data-attribute, all-ids, is cleared as well, which it should not. How can I clear selected-id without clearing all-ids.

#### files.js

```
function deselectAll() {
    $('input:checked').each(function(_, element) {
      $(element).prop('checked', false);
      $('#file-index').data('selected-ids').length = 0;
    });
  }
  function checkAllOnPage() {
    $('#selected_files').val('all');
    var selected = $('#file-index').data('selected-ids');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').each(function(_, element) {
      $(element).prop('checked', 'checked');
      selected.push($(element).val());
    });
    selected = compact(selected);
    toggleHeaderButton();
  }

  function checkAllOnPages() {
    $('#selected_files').val('all');
    var selected = $('#file-index').data('selected-ids');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').each(function(_, element) {
      $(element).prop('checked', 'checked');
    });
    $('#file-index').data('selected-ids', $('#file-index').data('all-ids'));
    toggleHeaderButton();
  }
```

#### index.html.slim

```
#file-index.files-index data-selected-ids=[] data-all-ids=@file_item_ids
  .row
    = render partial: 'shared/contents_title', locals: { hide_user_nav: false }
  - if @credential.present?
    #file-header.row
      = render "file_items/header"
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What they said. It sounds like setting it to zero is clearing it. Which is what you do and don't want...

Comment: why are you setting the length to 0 if you don't want to clear it?

Comment: Sorry I left out the name of the attribute, 'all-ids' which should not be changed but is.

Comment: ah - in that case I suspect something is going on that you're not yet showing us.  Can you reproduce this problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Can you share your original html, what you are expecting and what is happening?

Comment: @nikhil.agw I've added the relevant html

Comment: can you add a fiddle to show the issue?

Comment: Could you add a quetions ? Because its no so clear  to read your code. thanks.

Comment: @AntarrByrd - that's not HTML.  That's the server-side code that renders the HTML.

Comment: @andi It not relevant how the html is being generated. The question is only related to html and javascipt

Comment: @AntarrByrd yes but it helps us to see the actual HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting and updating the properties of an element's data object should be handled directly through the `data()` method in its role as a setter with two arguments.

If `selected-ids` is an array stored in the element's data object, you should reset it by passing the property's name and an empty array to the setter.

```
$('#file-index').data('selected-ids', []);
```

Comment: @wahwahwah Edited the answer. Made the difference between the two clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following in place of $('#file-index').data('selected-ids').length = 0;

```
$('#file-index').removeData('selected-ids');
```

Comment: @AntarrByrd Note that removing the property from the object in this manner would make it undefined. So the `length` property would not be defined either for any subsequent checks.